# uncaughtException don't workink as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js

Code Number 1:

```
process.on("uncaughtException", function(error){

    console.log('c')

})

console.log(abc)
```

Code Number 2:

```
console.log(abc)

process.on("uncaughtException", function(error){

    console.log('c')

})
```

why the code number 1 is working fine but code number 2 not?

Comment: Isn't it obvious? The second version tries to establish the error handler at a point in the code **after** the error has already happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Code Number 1 , you're handling  the error before it occurs.

In Code Number 2, the Error happens before you handle it, that's the reason it is not working.